# AngularJS - scope variable does not get updated from method

Tags: angularjs

I'm totally new to AngularJs and I have this problem I do not understand. I have two methods. The first one takes some data from a webservice and puts in in a variable defined in the scope. But when I want to use that variable in the second method it is undefined. Can someone help me understand why this is happening and provide a solution?

```
var myApp= angular.module( "myApp", [] );

myApp.controller("myAppController",
function( $scope ) {
$scope.getAll = function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: ..something...,
        success: function (parameters) {
            $scope.profiles = angular.copy(parameters);  <-- correct data is returned
            $scope.$apply();
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("Error calling the web service.");
        }
    });
}
$scope.getCategories = function(){
    var all = $scope.profiles;    <-- At this point profiles is empty
    ...
}
    $scope.getAll();
    $scope.getCategories();
}
```

Comment: use the `$http` service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no guarantee that `getAll` has completed before `getCategories` is invoked, since it is an asynchronous request. So if you want to sequentially invoke `getAll` and `getCategories`, you should invoke `getCategories` inside the `success` callback of `getAll`. You could also look into `promises` for a neater way of chaining asynchronous callbacks (I assume you're using jQuery since you're calling `$.ajax`).

```
...
<snipped some code>

success: function(parameters) {
    // snipped more code
    $scope.getCategories();
}
```

(and if you're using jQuery promises)

```
$.ajax(ajaxCallOneOpts).then($.ajax(ajaxCallTwoOpts));
```

Neither are very "Angularish" though, so you might want to look into some of the provided services for working with http/rest resources instead of using jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

When you call `getCategories()`, `getAll()` hasn't finished yet, which is why profiles is empty. There are several ways to solve this. The best way would be to use promises the built-in `$http` service.

If you prefer to use jQuery, you can add a watcher on the `profiles` variable and only when it's populated run the `getCategories()`.

Something like this should work:

```js
$scope.getAll = function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: ..something...,
        success: function (parameters) {
            $scope.profiles = angular.copy(parameters);  <-- correct data is returned
            $scope.$apply();
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("Error calling the web service.");
        }
    });
}

$scope.getCategories = function(){
    var all = $scope.profiles;

}

// Wait for the profiles to be loaded
$scope.watch('profiles', function() {
    $scope.getCategories();
}

$scope.getAll();
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the $http service and promises:

```
$scope.profiles = $http.jsonp(url).then(function(r){ return r.data; });
$scope.categories = $scope.profiles.then(function(profiles) {
  var params = { }; // build url params
  return $http.jsonp(url, { params: params }).then(function(r){ return r.data; });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using a jQuery ajax request in angular? If you write jQuery style code and wrap it angular, you're going to have a bad time...

Here is an angularised version:

```
myApp.controller("myAppController",
function( $scope, $q, $http ) {

  $scope.getAll = function(){
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $scope.profiles = deferred.promise;
    $http.jsonp('your url').then(function(data) {
      deferred.resolve(data);
    }); 
  });

  $scope.getCategories = function(){
    $q.when($scope.profiles).then(function(profiles) {  
       ... <-- At this point profiles is populated
    });    
  }

  $scope.getAll();
  $scope.getCategories();
}
```